# What is the meaning of a drag on profit ?

Tags: meaning

> But Intel’s failures in memory were becoming a drag on profits

According to the free dictionary

> **[Drag on:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drag+on)**
>
> 1. Last unnecessarily long
> 2. Proceed for an extended period of time

I think That meaning doesn't apply to the previous context, And i guessed that it may mean either a burden or a curse but i'm not sure about that.

So what do you think it means here?

Comment: *drag* here is a noun, not a verb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag here means to hinder, to make things difficult.
This is actually the more common usage of the word "Drag".

Specifically that the loss that Intel were making in their memory division prevented them making a larger company profit and thus wasn't worth having in the company.

Comment: I found it on the oxford dictionary thanks to you 
[in singular] a person or thing that impedes progress or development. 
So i think it means to impede or hinder